# Mongoose select elements in array based on a condition

Tags: mongoose

I have this simple Schema:

```
{
    bank: {
            transactions: [
                {
                    notify: Boolean
                }
            ]
    }
}
```

I just want to select the transactions with the notify flag set to true,
I have tried several ways using moongose, but non worked, example:

```
 Bank.findById("58efbb1a88efbf2028d2f5a7")
     .where("transactions.notify").equals(true)
     .exec(function (err, tx) {
         console.log(err);
         console.log(res);
         res.json(tx);
     });

Bank.find({_id: "58efbb1a88efbf2028d2f5a7", "transactions": {$elemMatch : {"notify" : true}}},
    function (err, txs) {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        } else {
            res.json(txs);
        }
    });
```

Is there anyway to do this using moongose?

Comment: when u say none worked, what has the result of your query been?

Comment: @ifiok the first one returns an empty object, the second one returns the whole (bank) object, if it have at least a transaction with notify set to true

Answer (score 0):

Use an aggregation with [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) and a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) :

```
Bank.aggregate([{
        "$match": {
            "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("58efbb1a88efbf2028d2f5a7")
        }
    }, {
        "$project": {
            "transactions": {
                "$filter": {
                    input: "$bank.transactions",
                    as: 'data',
                    cond: { "$eq": ["$$data.notify", true] }
                }
            }
        }
    }],
    function(err, txs) {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        } else {
            res.json(txs);
        }
    });
```

Comment: That returns null for transactions

Comment: From the model you posted in your question, it should work see [this sample input](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/dcab58e1a96f9b9ffbdbe737fd62c71d) which return only the transactions with `notify` set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bank.find({'_id': '58efbb1a88efbf2028d2f5a7', 'transactions.notify': true},
    function (err, txs) {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        } else {
            res.json(txs);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Nope that returns the whole array